# Update BIOS in Asus K55 laptop

Tags: laptop, asus, bios

I would like to update my laptop BIOS from ubuntu, cause I have no other OS in the machine.
The problem is that Asus provide only a windows bios-update program: http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K55VM/#download

Has anyone tried to do this from ubuntu in an Asus laptop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like they also have a built in tool to install the BIOS upgrades. In the Manual also provided on the ASUS site page A-15.

1. Download the BIOS upgrade from the link you provided.
2. Put the extracted file on a USB partition, using "FAT" file system not fat32 as stated [here](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?board_id=20&model=Eee%20PC%201008HA&id=20090616013029034&page=1&SLanguage=en-us).
3. Plug in the USB, then turn on the computer, press the key to get into BIOS on boot.
4. From the Manual follow these directions:

> 1. Use the Start Easy Flash function on the Advanced page of the BIOS Setup Utility. Follow the instructions shown.
> 2. Locate the latest BIOS file and start updating (flashing) the BIOS.
> 3. You must Restore Defaults on the Exit page after updating (flashing) the BIOS.

With this you should be able to upgrade your BIOS without Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I ve been looking for some thing like this. What do we do if we have multiple bios updates. Do we install the latest or will we have to install one by one from the oldest to the newest : http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K55VD/HelpDesk_Download/